# Regular Expression - doesn't start with AA or AD or ADL

Tags: expression

How can I find regular expression of every string doesn't start with AA or AD or ADL.

<<[[^AA][^AD][^ADL][a-zA-Z0-9-_]*]>> its not working.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
^(?!AA|ADL?)
```

Comment: <<(?!AA)(?!AD)(?!ADL)[a-zA-Z0-9-_]*>>